# Flutter : handle File.path null/empty

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `File` with name _pickedImage.
I facing problem with handle File.path null , I already handle `path` null with this code :

```
 if (pickedImage.path == null)
```

Or

```
if (pickedImage.path.isEmpty)
```

Everytime i press the button , i can't handle File.path `null` and i get this error.

```
═══════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The getter 'path' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: path

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#c9d89
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: possible
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(246.8, 613.3)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(246.8, 23.3)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
```

I'm doing mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
═══════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The getter 'path' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: path
```

The error is simply because you're trying to get the path from `null File`.

You need to check if the file is null or not before calling the next code:

```
 if (pickedImage == null) {
   // File is null, probably not found or incorrect path.
   return;
 }

 // Do something with the file
 if (pickedImage.path == null) {

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the variable `pickedImage` itself was a null.
try it like this

```
if(pickedImage?.path?.isEmpty != false)
```

or

```
if(pickedImage == null || pickedImage.path == null || pickedImage.path.isEmpty)
```